# How can I have the max size in the PXRichTextField set in DAC for HTML Editor in a Tab in a Custom Form like Item Description in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

The PXRichTextField - HTML Editor component is used in Stock Item, Non Stock Item - Description TAB. Insert also attaches Images in the data. The Image is displayed as well and the data is stored in Body field in the table. The files are stored in Upload Table.

How is MAX (Size)  (NVARCHAR(MAx) in SQL Server Database ) of Body Field entered in DAC ??

Comment: Just Refining the Question !

Answer (score 1):

To use a database column of type nvarchar(MAX) you'd specify the DAC field with a length of -1

`[PXDBString(-1)]`